# Does greasemonkey on firefox support @match?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, include, greasemonkey, match

I want to use the @match directive but do not want to break compatibility with greasemonkey.

Also, as unbelievable as it may seem, I don't have firefox installed on my system and thus can't test this myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Older versions of Greasemonkey will ignore the `@match` directive, but will not break.

For maximum compatibility, use the `@include` and `@exclude` directives to control where/when a script runs.

**Update:**
[As of Greasemonkey 0.9.8, GM fully supports the `@match` directive](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40match).

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I had hoped to hear. Also, that comparison link is much appreciated!

Comment: The comparison link went dead, It was pretty obsolete anyway as both GM and Chrome userscript support have been improving rapidly.

Comment: In Firefox 64, this directive no longer seems to work within the script. I have to specify it in the GreaseMonkey menu instead.

Comment: @reinierpost, `@match` still works fine for me, FF 64.0.2, GM 4.7.  But [best not to use Greasemonkey anyway](https://www.greasespot.net/2017/09/greasemonkey-4-for-users.html).  Use Tampermonkey or Violentmonkey (etc.).  Open a new question if you must, and use [the right tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/greasemonkey-4/info).

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks. I will test this when I have time and adjust the answer accordingly.